# Set minimum zoom level of webview (Android)

Tags: android, webview, zooming, minimum

I have a strange problem with a WebView I want to use to display an image and make it zoomable. I have the following method within my Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_manual);

    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);      
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/drawable/some_image.jpg");
    webView.setInitialScale(getScale());
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}
```

The `getScale()` method computes a scale I can use with `webView.setInitialScale()` to exactly scale my image to full screen width, and it works. The builtin zoom controls also work to some extent, but:

After I zoomed into the image, I can't zoom out back to my initial scale, I assume because the minimum scale is greater than my initial scale.

Setting the zoom density using WebSettings doesn't help, and I think even if it did on my phone it wouldn't on another.

What I also tried: I made an HTML-Page containing the image as only child of the body element. I set its width to 100% and also got it scaled right that way. However if I zoom in again, the image immediately is resized to again fit the screen width.

I found some answers, but none of them really helped:

```
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
    webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```

One solution mentioned employing reflection to change the WebView class to ignore the limits, but I fear this could break my app on some older versions of Android. I have to be compatible with devices down to API level 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found a solution for most situations like this, as long as we just want to load a single image. It's kind of a workaround, and loses some image details as it resizes the image. Nevertheless it should work on most if not all devices out there.

I followed the approach to embed the image into a basic HTML page, and filled the `<img>` tag with the width of the screen in pixels. For simplicity I skipped loading the HTML from a file and just generated it inside my Java code:

```
private String generatePage() {
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int displayWidth = display.getWidth();

    String result =
            "<html>"
            + "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"target-densitydpi=device-dpi,width=device-width\">"
            + "<head>"
            + " <title>Title</title>"
            + "</head>"
            + "<body>"
            + "<image id=\"myImage\" src=\"drawable/image.jpg\" width=\"" + displayWidth + "px\" />"
            + "</body>"
            + "</html>";
    return result;
}
```

I added this method to my Activity and used it to generate the code matching the device it runs on. The `onCreate()` method now can be pretty straightforward:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_manual);

    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/", generatePage(), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}
```

**Important note:** There are two details that you need to keep in mind, or it won't work.

1. You need to use the method `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(...)`, otherwise you can't access the local android ressources inside the HTML. This way the `src` attribute couldn't point to your image file.
2. You need the tag `<meta name="viewport" content="...">` inside your HTML code, and it has to include `target-densitydpi=device-dpi` inside its `content` attribute. Otherwise the size of the image may still not match your viewport.

*Note*: You also can specify a `minimal-scale` inside the `viewport`tag, and this really affected my webview. The bad thing: At least on my Galaxy S3 mini running Jelly Bean 4.1.2 a `minimal-scale` of less than 1.0 had no effect.

Answer (score -2):

May be this is what your are searching

```
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```